# Using find with a cloned jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

I have a particular JavaScript function that will accept either a jQuery selector, a plain object, or a jQuery object. In either case, the function's parameter is always passed to jQuery.

```js
function foo(selector)
{
    var i = 0;
    var items = new Array();
    $(selector).find('.myClass').each(function()
    {
        items[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
    }

    return items;
}
```

The function works as expected in jQuery 1.8, but does not work in jQuery 1.12+ (it never enters the .each). This style of code exists many places in the code base I am working with (1880 lines matching .find).

According to the jQuery website, when a jQuery object is passed to the jQuery function, a clone of that jQuery object is returned. I expect to functionally get the same object out that went in, but this isn't the case when using find. Find seems to expect either the original jQuery object, or the 0th element of a cloned object, ex: $("div").find(".myclass") and $($("div"))[0].find(".myclass") work but $($("div")).find(".myclass") does not.

The easiest solution I've come up with is to wrap the jQuery function to handle this, by causing it to immediately return any jQuery object passed in, rather than attempt jQuery's clone:

```js
(jQuery.fn.init = (function (init) {

    return function (selector) {
        if (selector instanceof jQuery) {
            return selector;
        }

        return init.apply(this, arguments);
    };

})(jQuery.fn.init)).prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

This works well, but are there are any "gotchas" I should be worried about? Is there a strong reason I should want a cloned jQuery object rather than a reference to the original?

Comment: Why do you want to stick with jQuery 1.12 when the problem is solved by using jQuery 1.18+?

Comment: There is no jQuery 1.18. jQuery 3.2.1 (the latest version) exhibits the same problem described in the question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with jQuery 3.2.1: https://jsfiddle.net/bmdhq4f2/

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for providing a jsfiddle, I should have started with one. Even when pasting the entire page markup into JSFiddle, I'm unable to reproduce the error, which leads me to believe there has to a conflict with internal libraries somewhere. A conflict that doesn't exist with jQuery 1.8...

Comment: Make sure you only access the DOM when the document has completely loaded. Put all of your code in a `$(function () { ..... });` wrapper to ensure that.

Comment: Thank you trincot. Yes, it is a form submission by the user, so the document is ready when it occurs.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, trincot. I should have run my simplified example through jsfiddle before asking the question; doing that may have led to the solution without needing to ask here. Hopefully I can submit better questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While no one could have known this without having the full source, there was a statement in the function before the error occurred:

```js
var selector = contentContainer.find("[TabId='EditProp']");
if (selector.length = 1 && selector.attr('PanelStatus') != '' && selector.attr('PanelStatus') != 'NewProp')
{
    propEditObj.PropNameData = foo($(selector));
}
```

It was the assignment of the selector.length property on the jQuery object (selector = 1 instead of selector == 1) which was somehow acceptable in jQuery 1.8.3, but caused strange breakage in 1.12.4+.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that return a clone, it should return the object with the contained pointer. 
You first code should work with one small change.
here is an example of how i would write it.

```js
function foo(selector)
{
    var i = 0; // no needed, use .push() instead
    var items = new Array();
    $(selector).each(function(){ // loop throw each object
    $(this).find('.myClass').each(function() // now try to find myClass, $(this) will always contain only one object
    {
        items.push($(this).val());
    }
    });
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that would work, but the issue isn't finding a solution for this one particular function, because I might have to apply that solution hundreds of times in different places (and I inevitably make a mistake trying to convert them all). I was wondering if the blanket solution was acceptable.

But if I have to go the hard road, I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: i think its ok to do it as you did, but i would override the find function for jquary and extended instead. it should be a good solution without any risk what so ever.